# Base converter not working java

Tags: java, binary, converters, radix

Okay so I am only trying to convert a base into base 10 right now, so disregard the base_out. The while statement near the bottom is what is being problematic. I jUnitTest like this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
      Assert.assertEquals("0", NumberBase.convert("0000", 2, 10));
      Assert.assertEquals("1", NumberBase.convert("0001", 2, 10));
      Assert.assertEquals("2", NumberBase.convert("0010", 2, 10));
      Assert.assertEquals("3", NumberBase.convert("0011", 2, 10));
      Assert.assertEquals("4", NumberBase.convert("0100", 2, 10));
      Assert.assertEquals("5", NumberBase.convert("0101", 2, 10));
      Assert.assertEquals("6", NumberBase.convert("0110", 2, 10));
      Assert.assertEquals("7", NumberBase.convert("0111", 2, 10));
      Assert.assertEquals("8", NumberBase.convert("1000", 2, 10));
```

It keeps giving me the output 18 for the third test where I expect 2. I have been looking over this for a while and cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
public static String convert(String input, int base_in, int base_out){
    String str = "";

    for (int index = 0; index < input.length(); index++) {
        char aChar = input.charAt(index);
        sum = Character.getNumericValue(aChar);
        result.add(sum);
    }

    i = 0;
    sum = 0;
    while(i < result.size()){
        sum += (int) (result.get(result.size()-1-i))*(Math.pow(base_in, i));
        i++;

    }
    str = "" + sum;

    return str;
}
```

Comment: I ran this on my machine and got the expected results for the "0010" case.

Comment: I got the same result as @Kon, i.e. that it works as is. The only thing I had to do was to provide declarations for `int sum` and `List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();`. Perhaps there is something in the code you left out that doesn't work?

Comment: I have used JUnit to test all of your assertions John, and they all passed without errror. I did as @Steinar did and declared two local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only assume this happens because `result` appears to be a `static` variable that you aren't reassigning/clearing/re-initializing on each method call and therefore still holds the previous values, the `sum` you added on previous calls.

Either make it local to the method

```
public static String convert(String input, int base_in, int base_out){
    List<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>();
    ...
```

Or reinitialize it at the start (to clear the previous sums)

```
public static String convert(String input, int base_in, int base_out){
    result = new LinkedList<>(); // or just call clear()
    ...
```

Proof: `0000` + `0001` + `0010` = `000000010010` = 18

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much! I will accept as answer in 4 minutes when I'm allowed to!

Comment: @JohnTunisi You are welcome. This is one of the dangers of `static` fields and methods, you're always interacting with the same object. Try to use instance fields and methods as much as possible.